# Set of null-sequences is not $\sigma$-compact

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, real-analysis

I am interested in a **reference** for the following fact (or a similar result).

> **PROPOSITION.** Let $X$ denote the set of real null sequences; i.e., the set of $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ with $a_n\to 0$, with the usual (product) topology. Then $X$ is not $\sigma$-compact.

By definition, $X$ is $F_{\sigma \delta}$ in the space of all real sequences. Since $X$ is a subset of the space of all bounded real sequences, which is $\sigma$-compact, the claim is equivalent to saying that $X$ is not $F_{\sigma}$. The proof of the proposition is not difficult (see below). I am using a similar proof in [my recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16946) that shows that the escaping set of a transcendental entire function is never $\sigma$-compact. It would therefore be useful to know of a reference for the above, which feels as though it should be classical.

> **Proof of the Proposition.** If $\underline{a} = (a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}\in X$ is a null sequence, and $\varepsilon>0$, set
> $$ n_{\varepsilon}(\underline{a}) := \min\{n\geq 0\colon |a_n| < \varepsilon\} < \infty.$$
> Clearly for all sequences $(\varepsilon_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ and $(N_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ with $\varepsilon_k\to 0$, there is $\underline{a}\in X$ such that
> $$ n_{\varepsilon_k}(\underline{a}) > N_k$$
> for all $k\geq 0$. (This is just saying that there are sequences that tend to zero arbitrarily slowly.)
> If $A\subset X$ is compact, then
> $$ n_{\varepsilon}(A) := \max_{\underline{a}\in A} n_{\varepsilon}(\underline{a}) < \infty.$$
> Let $(A_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of compact subsets of $X$. Let
> $\underline{a}\in X$ be such that $$ n_{1/k}(\underline{a}) > n_{1/k}(A_k)$$
> for all $k\geq 0$. Then $\underline{a}\notin A_k$ for all $k$, and hence
> $$ X \neq \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k,$$
> as claimed.

Answer (score 3):

This is in Exercise 23.11 in [the textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4190-4) of Kechris (and follows from the $\mathbf \Pi^0_3$-completeness of this space).

The topological (infinite-dimensional) structure of this space is described in Corollary 5.5.16 of van Mill's book "[The infinite-dimensional topology of function spaces](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-infinite-dimensional-topology-of-function-spaces/van-mill/978-0-08-092977-4)".

Comment: The space is not even $\sigma$-complete by Exercise 23.11.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to get hold of a copy of that book.